# Stata: Generating variables in a loop using tuples local macro

Tags: stata

I need to generate all possible tuples of the integer numbers 1,2,3,4 (with exactly 2 items in each tuple).Then, I need to `generate` a set of variables that would correspond to the resulting six tuples. Each variable name should contain a reference to a tuple and the value of each variable should be a string version of a tuple itself, as illustrated below:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| var_12 | var_13 | var_14 | var_23 | var_24 | var_34 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     12 |     13 |     14 |     23 |     24 |     34 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

While the tuples are generated by using the `tuples` user-written command (for details, see http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s456797.html), I am stumbling with generating new variables and assigning values to them in a loop. The code looks as follows and results in a syntax error which presumably stems from using local tuples macros incorrectly, and I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me solving it.

```
tuples 1 2 3 4, display min(2) max(2)

forval i = 1/`ntuples' {
    gen v`i'=`tuple`i''  
    rename v`i' var_`tuple`i''
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tuples` is a user-written command from SSC. Over at [www.statalist.org](http://www.statalist.org) you would be expected to explain where it comes from, and that's a very good idea here too.

In your case, you want say integers such as 12 to represent a tuple such as "1 2" but the latter looks malformed to Stata when you are creating a numeric variable. Stata certainly won't elide the space(s) even if all characters presented otherwise are numeric. So you need to do that explicitly. At the same name giving a variable one name and then promptly renaming it can be compressed.

```
forval i = 1/`ntuples' {
    local I : subinstr local tuple`i' " " "", all 
    gen var_`I' = `I' 
}
```

Creating a string variable for the tuple with space included would make part of that unnecessary, but the space is still not allowed in the variable name:

```
forval i = 1/`ntuples' {
    local I : subinstr local tuple`i' " " "_", all      
    gen var_`I' = "`tuple`i''"  
}
```

If this is the whole of your problem, it would have been quicker to write out 6 `generate` statements! If this is a toy problem representative of something larger, watch out that say "1 23" and "12 3" would both be mapped to "123", so eliding the spaces is unambiguous only with single digit integers; hence the appeal of holding strings as such.

I am still curious how holding the same tuple in every observation of a variable is a good idea; perhaps your larger purpose would be better met by using string scalars or the local macros themselves.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, it worked perfectly. 
I agree that generating string scalars would be easier (here my example constitutes the entire actual problem, and lateron I need to verify whether the values of another variable match either of the six tuples), but my idea was to automatize the process and using tuples seemed as a way out.